# GCM sometimes works, sometimes doesn't

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

My aplication is a multiplayer game in android, with a server running on google app engine and using GCM to conect the server with the player devices. i have registered the device in GCM and then i sent the registerId to the server to connect with the device. When i run the game sometimes it works fine but sometimes the device doesn¡t receive anything from GCM, the server still receive from the device. I have no idea what is happening :s

Here is where i register my device in the onCreate of the main class :

```
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
    if (GCMRegistrar.isRegistered(this)) {
        Log.d("info", GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this));
    }
    regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    deviceId = getDeviceId();
    if (regId.equals("")) {
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
        Log.d("info", GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this));
    }
```

Then the first time i run the application on a phone i use this code to send the registationId to the server:

```
sendMessage("code=" + REGISTRATION_CODE + 
            "&deviceId=" + deviceId + 
            "&regId=" + regId  + 
            "&phoneNumber=" + phoneNumber);
```

And here is the code in the server to send messages back to the device:

```
public void sendMessage(String regId, String text) {
    Sender sender = new Sender(APIKey);
    Message message = new Message.Builder().collapseKey("1").timeToLive(3).delayWhileIdle(true).addData("message", text).build();
    try {
        sender.send(message,regId,1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();//Manejar la excepcion
    }
}
```

I can't understand why stop working, i'm in the middle of a game and stops working and then works again ...

Answer (score 1):

I just solved it, the problem was the collapseKey here

```
Message message = new Message.Builder().collapseKey("1").timeToLive(3).delayWhileIdle(true).addData("message", text).build();
```

If you use the same collapseKey always sometimes you don't receive messages randomly so i try this and works finally works!!

```
Message message = new Message.Builder().collapseKey(""+((int) (Math.random () * (10000)))).timeToLive(3).delayWhileIdle(true).addData("message", text).build();
```